# How can I write a java application using JMX code to get the active session's in tomcat 7?

Tags: java, tomcat7, jmx

I am using the apache **tomcat 7** to run my web application. I need to know the number of active sessions by running a java application.

I have read that it is possible by using **JMX**. I got the count by using **jconsole**. But using a java application I need to get it.

Can anyone please help me start it.

Comment: Where in your code do you have the problem? With [JMX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) itself or with finding the [MBean names](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/funcspecs/mbean-names.html).

Comment: I don't know where to start or how to start. So please help me to write a java application to read active sessions from tomcat. What all things should I learn to write an application.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to so. Asking about tutorials is off-topic. Since you don't have any code or an actual problem to discuss here, I vote to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach would be

```
String serviceUrl = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9001/jmxrmi";
JMXServiceURL jmxServiceUrl = new JMXServiceURL(serviceUrl);
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(jmxServiceUrl, null);
MBeanServerConnection conn = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
ObjectName name = new ObjectName("Catalina:type=ProtocolHandler,port=8080");
System.out.println(conn.getAttribute(name, "connectionCount"));
```

To find out more about Tomcat monitoring have a look at [Monitoring and Managing Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/monitoring.html) (or on your local installation http://localhost:8080/docs/monitoring.html) and in the [FAQ - Monitoring](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Monitoring)

**edit** To find the active sessions of an application amend the example accordingly. The below two lines will show the acctive sessions if you access the [SessionExample](http://localhost:8080/examples/servlets/servlet/SessionExample)  from the default Tomcat installation.

```
ObjectName name = new ObjectName(
    "Catalina:type=Manager,context=/examples,host=localhost");
System.out.println(conn.getAttribute(name, "activeSessions"));
```

Comment: I tried this before. But I am getting an error "java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException" like this. How do we get the service url?

Comment: @SreevidyaAravind This is explained follwing the link `Monitoring and Managing Tomcat` in the section `Enabling JMX Remote`.

Comment: That error got solved after restarting tomcat. But now I have a doubt regarding the context specification. How do I specify the context? ObjectName name = new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Manager,context=/testApp,host=localhost,port=8080"); This is how I have specified it . But not working